# How to expand textarea width to 100% of parent (or how to expand any HTML element to 100% of parent width)?

Tags: html, css

How to expand textarea width to 100% of parent?

I try width 100% but it is not works it expands to 100% of page what crash layout.

Here the question in visual way.
[image]

Please provide some hints.

Comment: Post your relevant HTML and the CSS

Comment: You must show your code. I suspect it has something to do with positioning on the parent element and so there is no reference point for the text area. But I can't tell you for sure without _seeing some code_!

Comment: Width does not include paddings and margins. If you want to make a box 100% you can set `width: auto;` for blocks, otherwise you should calculate the width by substracting the margin and padding. check out more information about to box model: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Comment: Apart from the code, can you indicate please what browser support you want?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```html
<div>
  <div style="width: 20%; float: left;">
    <p>Some Contentsssssssssss</p>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 80%;">
    <textarea style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%;"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does it work? i.e. why wrapping <textarea> with a div and setting some properties work in terms of CSS fundamentals?

Answer (score 16):

The [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) is something every web-developer should know about. working with percents for sizes and pixels for padding/margin just doesn't work. There always is a resolution at which it doesn't look good (e.g. giving a width of 90% and a padding/margin of 10px in a div with a width of under 100px).

Check this out (using micro.pravi's code): http://jsbin.com/umeduh/2

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="content">
            left
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="content">
            right
            <textarea>Check me out!</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `<div class="content">` are there so you can use padding and margin without screwing up the floats.

this is the most important part of the CSS:

```
textarea {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Almost good (missed floating). box-sizing == CSS3 better use old CSS2 if you not want limit you application by design.

Comment: to be honest, this should be the answer, 100% width is correct. What's incorrect is how the browser calculates it.

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` was the one thing that finally solved my particular use case.

Answer (score 10):

You need to define `width` of the div containing the `textarea` and when you declare `textarea`, you can then set `.main > textarea` to have `width: inherit`.

Note: `.main > textarea` means a `<textarea>` inside of an element with `class="main"`.

Here is the [working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/s3ceK/)

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="main">
    <textarea name="" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 20%;
  background: #cccccc;
  display: table-cell;
}

.main {
  width: 80%;
  background: gray;
  display: inline;
}

.main > textarea {
  width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Try not condense code - it makes it less readable what is the most important in coding - not compression. Pretty indentation is not to keep code beauty but only code quality and readability. Readable code can be faster reviewed and has less errors (2x 4x times).

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="content">
        <textarea cols="2" rows="10" id="rules"></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:5px;

}
#left{
    width:20%;
height:400px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:block;
}
#content{
    width:78%;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
textarea
{
   margin-top:100px;
    width:98%;
}
```

DEMO:
[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mUqZE/)

Comment: is it height: auto not default value in css - http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/height ? Clear is need here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..Add this in your page

```
<style>
textarea
{
width:100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Wrong idea it is global settings never do it.

Comment: this one is a basic logic,you create style with specific name and then apply to the specific textarea..

Answer (score 0):

Add the css

```
  <style type="text/css">
    textarea
    {

        border:1px solid #999999
        width:99%;
        margin:5px 0;
        padding:1%;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: 1% = unknown - it is not responsible layout can or not work use better em.

Comment: @Chameleon Thanks for your Recommendation

Comment: I think it will save a lot of time on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="side">sidebar here</div>
    <div class="main">
        <textarea class="taclass"></textarea>
    </div>
</div><!--/ wrapper -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.side{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
}
.main{
    float:right;
    width:80%;
}
.taclass{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    padding:2%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: The point is to inherit the width and not declare a width in value. By declaring a value, you are manually solving the purpose, which instead should be solved by a strategic CSS Solution.

Comment: I saw your method above but in fact that the wrapper is not fully in 100% width?

Comment: That is because I have not defined a `table-cell` for the second div.

Comment: Percent is not ok since it is not relative - it is ok for 20%, 80% and for nothing else.

Comment: If you wish 95% something you can make container with padding: 1em; (not %!).

Comment: Don't add markup to do clearing, this isn't semantic! Use a clearfix instead.

Comment: @Soviut: that one was added by someone, not me. I have edited the code above for clearing floats